# Realtime value from range input to array in onload function

Tags: javascript, function, opencv, input, range

.Hello! I want realtime value from range input to array in onload function (I use opencv.js and vanilla) :

```
<input type="range" min="0" max="179" oninput="myFunction(this.value);">
```

```
imgElement.onload = () => {
   let array = [HERE I WANT REAL TIME VALUE FROM INPUT RANGE,2,3,4];
}
```

With my skill I can send this value only when onload function is ready or I can do this:

```
function myFunction(e){
    let array = [parseInt(e),2,3,4];
}
```

But I can't achieve realtime result on imgElement.onload function.

I will be grateful for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps.

```js
let fullArray = [];  //Empty init array
function inputValueChanged(){
 let value = parseInt(document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value); //Gathering value
 fullArray = [value,2,3,4];  //Changing the array
 console.log(fullArray);
}
window.onload = () => {
  inputValueChanged();  //Calling the function when window is loaded.
}
```

```html
<input type="range" min="0" max="179" onchange={inputValueChanged()}>
```

Comment: Also, if you want to wait for a specific element to load (imgElement), use document.getElementById('imgElement').onload instead of window.onload.

Comment: Thanks for reply! This works good but no in my case:( I use OpenCV and this how it works without realtime value: let array = [1, 2, 3,4];         let low = new cv.Mat(src.rows, src.cols, src.type(), array); . How I can put inputValueChanged here?

Comment: You need to call inputvalueChanged before you use any OpenCV functions so that the array is updated.

Comment: I do everything what you say, but when i use Input Range this don;t work realtime, I can set range to for example 179 and it work only when i load new image(when imgElement.onload function play)

Answer (score 0):

So this is all code now and realtime don't work:

```
let fullArray = [];
function inputValueChanged(){
  let value = parseInt(document.querySelector('.input1').value)
  fullArray = [value,2,3,4];
  console.log(fullArray)
}
imgElement.onload = () => {
inputValueChanged();
let ARRAY = fullArray;
let low = new cv.Mat(src.rows, src.cols, src.type(), ARRAY);
}
```